# Get Time Slot Column (SQL Query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have this table with a column ScheduledTime which holds DateTime values; These are start time of 
3hr Tests.
The column looks something like this:

```
SELECT ScheduledTime from Schedule;

2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-16 16:34:36.000
2012-03-20 09:14:48.000
2012-03-20 13:14:48.000
2012-03-20 17:14:48.000
2012-03-20 21:14:48.000
2012-04-14 17:13:19.000
2012-04-14 21:13:19.000
2012-04-15 01:13:19.000
2012-04-15 05:13:19.000
2012-04-15 09:13:19.000
2012-04-15 13:13:19.000
2012-04-15 17:13:19.000
2012-04-15 21:13:19.000
2012-04-16 01:13:19.000
2012-04-16 05:13:19.000
2012-04-16 13:13:19.000
2012-04-16 17:13:19.000
2012-04-17 01:13:19.000
2012-04-17 05:13:19.000
2012-04-17 13:13:19.000
2012-04-18 18:29:16.000
2012-04-19 15:48:12.000
2012-04-19 19:10:00.000
2012-04-19 23:47:00.000
2012-04-20 10:27:28.000
2012-04-20 17:27:00.000
```

The datetime values listed above are start times for 3hr tests. So I need to get the next available slot for a 3hr test. Best would be if it can be accomodated within the existing tests or currentTime+1hr.

The task is to generate a column (say SlotsColumn) which holds start time for 3hr slots obtained from the ScheduledTime column and the SlotsColumn value is > {fn Now()} i.e. CurrentTime.

Optional is that if it doesn't have any such value, it should give CurrentTime+1hr

Using SQL Server 2008.

```
I have tried this:  
WITH rows AS 
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ScheduledTime] ) AS rn 
        FROM    [dbo].[Schedule]  
        WHERE [ScheduledTime] IS NOT NULL               
        ) 
SELECT  TOP(1)
DATEADD(second,10800, mc.ScheduledTime) AS NextTime 
FROM    rows mc 
JOIN    rows mp   
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1   
WHERE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.ScheduledTime, mp.ScheduledTime) - 10800) >= 10800 
order by mc.ScheduledTime DESC
```

The query returns list of one valid start time in the future, only if it exists.

To the sample data above, it returns '2012-04-20 03:47:00.000' which is wrong as it doesn't consider that there is another test at '2012-04-20 17:27:00.000'. They should not overlap.
The desired output is: '2012-04-20 12:27:00.000' as, it is after the test at '2012-04-20 10:27:28.000' and before the test at '2012-04-20 17:27:00.000', so perfect slot for a 3hr test.
The CurrentTime for me is '2012-04-20 11:45:23.393'

How do I ensure that it returns CurrentTime+1hr if no such valid time exists?

It can be done in C#, but trying SQL Query.

Any help/hints please.

Comment: What have you tried? Attach desired output please. Is there another column like `id` and are the `id`s then sorted by `ScheduledTime`?

Comment: You need a query to find all instances of `ScheduledTime` which have a clear 3hr window after them. If no clear window found, it should return CurrentTime+1hr?

Comment: I have been trying this:


  
`WITH rows AS 
  (
  SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ScheduledTime] ) AS rn 
  FROM    [dbo].[Schedule]  
  WHERE [ScheduledTime] IS NOT NULL    
  ) 
SELECT  
DATEADD(second,10800, mc.ScheduledTime) AS NextTime 
FROM    rows mc 
JOIN    rows mp   
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1   
WHERE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.ScheduledTime, mp.ScheduledTime) - 10800) >= 10800 
AND DATEADD(second,10800, mc.ScheduledTime) > {fn Now()}
order by mc.ScheduledTime`

Yes there is a ScheduleID.
Didnt get your question "are the ids then sorted by ScheduledTime".

Comment: @Paddy Yes. Thats the thing I am trying.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear of what output you require. If I understand you correctly, you're looking for 3-hour time slots available between two consecutive schedules, where the timeslot > now? i.e. from the data you have supplied, 2012-03-16 19:34:36.000...

Comment: @Tombom the above couldnt be formatted correctly, if it's not helpful please check this 
[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8203729/1.png)

Comment: @Peter sorry for not being clear. The datetime values listed above are start times for 3hr tests. So I need to get the next available slot for a 3hr test. Best would be if it can be accomodated within the existing tests or currentTime+1hr. I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: @dushyantp Please could you move your code to an edit of the original question? There would be more space to read it, and it would get formatted properly.

Comment: Could you put what your expected results are for your sample data

Comment: @Bridge I have put the query, changed it slightly (as compared to my comment earlier). Check the original question edit.

Comment: @Paddy updated the question with the expected result. 
If you noticed my earlier comment, it was wrong data included in it. Very sorry for that.

Comment: Your example returns `2012-04-20 13:27:28.000`, which is a valid time and doesn't overlap with the later time of `2012-04-20 17:27:00.000`.

Comment: What do you mean by "no such valid time exists"? Such a valid time always exists (at worst in 3 hours after your last test ends).

Comment: Yes you are right @Quassnoi . I meant "no valid time exists within the existing slots". The worst case slot is definitely 3hrs after the latest test start time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that has finally worked and achieved the desired result is:

```
    WITH rows AS 
                (
                SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ScheduledTime] ) AS rn 
                FROM    Schedule
                WHERE [ScheduledTime] IS NOT NULL                     
                ) 
    SELECT  COALESCE 
            ( 
            (
            SELECT  Top 1
            DateAdd(SECOND,-10800,mp.ScheduledTime) AS NewNextTime
            FROM    rows mc 
            JOIN    rows mp   
            ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1   
            WHERE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.ScheduledTime, mp.ScheduledTime) - 10800) >= 10800 
            And mp.ScheduledTime >= GETDATE()
            And DateAdd(SECOND,-10800,mp.ScheduledTime)>= GETDATE()
            order by mc.ScheduledTime
            ),
            ( 
            SELECT  TOP 1 
                    DATEADD(hour, 3, scheduledTime) AS NewNextTime 
            FROM    Schedule s 
            WHERE   s.scheduledTime >= DATEADD(hour, -3, GetDate()) 
                    AND NOT EXISTS 
                    ( 
                    SELECT  NULL 
                    FROM    Schedule sn 
                    WHERE   sn.scheduledTime > s.scheduledTime 
                            AND sn.scheduledTime < DATEADD(hour, 6, s.scheduledTime) 
                    ) 

            ORDER BY 
                    scheduledTime 
            ),
           (
                SELECT  TOP 1 
                DATEADD(SECOND, (3600), GetDate()) AS NewNextTime 
            )  
            )
```

This returns a valid time or in worst case scenario the time after the end of the last test.

The first part of SELECT COALESCE, returns a time slot from within existing slots.
The second part of SELECT COALESCE, returns a time slot at the end of all the test slots.
The third part of  SELECT COALESCE, returns as CurrentTime+1hr.

The discussion on this by all of you was very helpful to arrive at this. I will still look for better suggestions, as of now will use this one.

P.S. Sorry for the delay in posting this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2 = '2012-04-20 11:45:23.393'
DECLARE @schedule TABLE
        (
        ScheduledTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
        )

INSERT
INTO    @schedule
VALUES 
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-16 16:34:36.000'),
('2012-03-20 09:14:48.000'),
('2012-03-20 13:14:48.000'),
('2012-03-20 17:14:48.000'),
('2012-03-20 21:14:48.000'),
('2012-04-14 17:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-14 21:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 01:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 05:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 09:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 13:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 17:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-15 21:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-16 01:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-16 05:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-16 13:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-16 17:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-17 01:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-17 05:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-17 13:13:19.000'),
('2012-04-18 18:29:16.000'),
('2012-04-19 15:48:12.000'),
('2012-04-19 19:10:00.000'),
('2012-04-19 23:47:00.000'),
('2012-04-20 10:27:28.000'),
('2012-04-20 17:27:00.000')

SELECT  COALESCE
        (
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                DATEADD(hour, 3, scheduledTime)
        FROM    @schedule s
        WHERE   s.scheduledTime >= DATEADD(hour, -3, @now)
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    @schedule sn
                WHERE   sn.scheduledTime > s.scheduledTime
                        AND sn.scheduledTime < DATEADD(hour, 6, s.scheduledTime)
                )

        ORDER BY
                scheduledTime
        ),
        DATEADD(hour, 1, @now)

-- This is redundant

        )
```

Comment: The above query seems to be returning CurrentTime+1hr all the time.

I tried run it against:
`2012-04-20 14:20:40.183`
`2012-04-20 17:27:00.000`
`2012-04-20 23:27:00.000`

The CurrentTime is 2012-04-20 13:29:20.177 and it returns 2012-04-20 14:29:32.467, when it should return around 2012-04-20 20:27:32.467.

BTW, interesting, I never knew of this type of query. Thanks. I am investigating further on this line.

Comment: The change returns the Worst Case time at all times. I ran it against: 2012-04-20 23:27:00.000, 2012-04-21 02:27:00.000
and it returns 2012-04-21 05:27:00.000, where as since there are no tests scheduled at CurrentTime+1, it should return that.

It is very helpful though. I think I can tweak this query of yours to reach the solution, lets see.

Comment: @dushyantp: for your example in the first comment, it returned `2012-04-20 20:27:00.0000000`. This is not the worst time. Also, please post full code to reproduce the problems (as an update to your original post).

Comment: in the first comment, I said it should return 2012-04-20 20:27:00.0000000 but it was not doing so. BTW I have used your idea as part of the solution. Please check the answer. Thanks a Lot.